# Is class declaration and object initialization in the same file PSR-1 compliant?

Tags: php, psr-1

[PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) states:

> Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants,
>   etc.) or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini
>   settings, etc.) but SHOULD NOT do both.

Let's suppose we have following code:

```
// db.php file
class Db{
    // Some code here
}

$DB = new Db();
```

Does instantiating an object count as causing a side effect? In other words, is the above code PSR-1 compliant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PSR-1

> "Side effects" include but are not limited to: [...]
>    connecting to external services [...]

And more generally, it is specified :

> The phrase "side effects" means execution of logic **not directly**
>   **related** to declaring classes, functions, constants

So the answer is : it is not PSR-1 compliant.

You should include your `db.php` file in your main logic file. And then instanciate your DB object.